# show modified date category list joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, components, joomla1.5

How to modify the component "com_content" in joomla 1.5 to show the article's modified date istead created date the category in list view??

I tried replacing the "created" value with "modified" but Im not sure what files to modify.

Answer (score 1):

No, that shows the modified date within each article. But when you go to the category list view, the created date is still the one that shows. And even if you go into that category and hide 'created' and show 'modified' it still only impacts the article and not the category list view.

Answer (score 0):

Click Article Manager

Click Parameters [top right]

Click Modified Date and Time -> Show

Hide the Created Date.